The token is not installed in the headers
The thing is that I'm trying to get a token from a cookie using the ready-made CookieService library and output it to console.log() - and the most interesting thing is that it is displayed in console.log() and even written to the headers, but the client still gives me an error side - No token provided , I really don’t understand the options for solving this problem anymore, apparently there is a problem in my code that I don’t see
Here is my Interceptor where I am trying to set the token in the headers
I will provide the most basic code that is needed
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { TokenService } from '../services/token/token.service';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private tokenService: TokenService, private cookieService: CookieService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const accessToken = this.cookieService.get('accessToken');
    
    if (accessToken) {
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.error('Access token not found in cookie');
    }

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------
const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Authentication failed' });
        }

        const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (!isPasswordValid) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Authentication failed' });
        }

        const { accessToken, refreshToken } = generateTokens(user);

        res.cookie('accessToken', accessToken, {
            maxAge: 30000
        });

        res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
            maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        });

        res.status(200).json({ accessToken, refreshToken });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
};
--------------------------------------------------------------------
const getUserById = async (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.id;

    let user;
    try {
        user = await User.findById(userId, "-password");
        console.log('User', user);
    } catch(err) {
        return new Error(err);
    }
    if(!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({message: "User not found"});
    }
    return res.status(200).json({user});
};
--------------------------------------------------------------------
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const authorizationHeader = req.headers.authorization;

  if (!authorizationHeader) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "No token provided" });
  }
  console.log('AuthHeader', authorizationHeader);

  const token = authorizationHeader.split(' ')[1];
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "No token found" });
  }
  console.log('Tokenssss', token);

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error verifying token:', err);
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid token" });
    }

    req.id = decoded.userId;
    next();
  });
};

module.exports = verifyToken;


**And routes **
router.post('/login', userAuthController.login);
router.get('/user', verifyToken, userAuthController.getUserById);


